# Need to place a Controller outside the app\Http\Controllers folder and add routes to it

Tags: php, laravel-5

I dont believe it, it seems this is not possible in Laravel.

I need to do something like this in routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('logout', 'App\MyModule\LogoutController@logout');
```

***It seems I can't do that in Laravel!***

NOTE: I **DO NOT** WANT TO CHANGE THE GLOBAL PROJECT CONFIGURATION LIKE [THIS ANSWER](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/registering-a-controller-outside-from-the-controllers-folder) IS PROPOSING

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Route::get('logout', function () {
            return App::call('\App\MyModule\LogoutController@logout');
        });
```